# Configuring repeater control using VB

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm trying to create a repeater control and I've run in to a slight problem. Below is the repeater control code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="movies" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Movie Title: <%# Container.DataItem("MovieTitle")%>
                </th>
                <th>
                    Genre: <%# Container.DataItem("Genre")%>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Container.DataItem("Synopsis")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Staring: <%# Container.DataItem("Starring")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Director: <%# Container.DataItem("Director")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

VB Code behind for the control is:

```
movie_title = Request.QueryString("id")
    myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & _
                Server.MapPath("../App_Data/MovieBoard.accdb"))
    myConn.Open()
    Dim sqlQuery = "Select movieID From Movies"
    Dim aCmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, myConn)
    aDataReader = aCmd.ExecuteReader()

    If aDataReader.Read() = True Then
        movieID = aDataReader(0)
    Else
        movieID = "0"
    End If

    query = ("Select MovieTitle, Genre, Synopsis, Starring, Director From Movies")
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, myConn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    movies.DataSource = dr
    movies.DataBind()
```

However when I run the code I get an:

```
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

Line 12:         Dim query, movie_title, movieID As String
Line 13:         movie_title = Request.QueryString("id")
Line 14:         myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & _
Line 15:                     Server.MapPath("../App_Data/MovieBoard.accdb"))
Line 16:         myConn.Open()
```

I think the problem is something small but I don't seem to be able to find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Server.MapPath you're using. Try:

```
Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MovieBoard.accdb")
```

The ../ is asking for the folder one level up, and the error telling you it can't go any higher.

Comment: You should also be able to use `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MovieBoard.accdb")`

Comment: Thank you so much JonLord. I knew it was something small.